# Extract and overwrite existing files

Tags: command-line, 7-zip, switching

I am trying to write a batch script to extract files out of an existing [ZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_%28file_format%29) file, into another folder on my desktop and to have the system not prompt me as to whether I want to overwrite the existing files or not. The script works with just `-o`, but once I add -aoa, I get an error:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" e file1.zip "-aoaC:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\all_backup_files"
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The 7-Zip command line options you will need are `x`, `-o` and `-y`:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" x file1.zip -o"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\all_backup_files" -y
```

<sup>Note there mustn't be a gap between -o and the folder name.</sup>

If you type `7z --help` you will get a list of valid parameters.

Comment: Thanks very much for this Sean. For me it was where to put the switch. I fixed the batch programs and they all work great now.

Answer (score 4):

```
"C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" e file1.zip " -aoa -o"C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Desktop\all_backup_files"
```

<sup>Note there mustn't be a gap between -o and the folder name.</sup>

this will solve the problem
refer https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/overwrite.htm

Comment: Welcome to Super User. On this Q&A site we value answers that remain useful if/when linked material becomes inaccessable. Please [edit] your answer so that it includes the essential elements from your linked source.

Comment: On top of which, this doesn't seem to work. Not sure if it's a version issue, but pasting this exact command into my CLI results in the error "Too long switch".
Despite when I check --help, the -aoa switch is listed.

The only command that worked for me is SeanC's above.

Comment: @CarlSteinhilber - `-aoa` works - I fixed the space after the `-o` parameter which throws this oddball CLI exception