# Batch File for Download + Unzip (.7z) + Delete + Rename

Tags: command-line, batch, 7-zip

I would like to create a .bat file in order to download and make following operations on 2 files (FILE1-Date.7z & FILE2-Date.7z) whose names are updated with "Date" information everyday. The batch file should do the below operations automatically ;

1. Download FILE1-Date.7z & FILE2-Date.7z from internet page (i.e. https://collaboration.xxxgroup.com) into specified folder (D:/etc...), and this page requires username & password.
2. Extract the files (file type is .mdb) inside .7z files to the same folder in which .7z files exist
3. Delete old (existing) files (FILE1.mdb & FILE2.mdb) in the folder
4. Rename FILE1-Date.mdb to FILE1.mdb & FILE2-Date.mdb to FILE2.mdb

Is it possible to do these operations by using a batch file or I need to use a totally different tool? Any suggestions?

NOTE : Changed "intranet" with "internet" in step 1, and added more details about web site that I will download the files. Also changed naming format of file WAS: FILE_Date BECOME: FILE-Date (example:  LANGUAGES-26-01-2015)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a batch file to do this. Without more details, it's hard to provide specifics, but in general, do the following:

- Use the copy command to copy from the intranet to the specified folder.
- Use %PROGRAMFILES%\7-Zip\7z.exe for extracting files and overwriting older ones. [More Help Here](https://superuser.com/questions/483037/extract-and-overwrite-existing-files).
- Use the following for getting the current date:

```
    set DT=

    for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%A in ('wmic os get localdatetime') do (
        if not defined DT set DT=%%A)

    set YYYY=%DT:~0,4%
    set MM=%DT:~4,2%
    set DD=%DT:~6,2%
    set DATE=%YYYY%_%MM%_%DD%
```

- Use the following to rename your file_date.mdb files to file.mdb:

```
    for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%A in ('dir /b *.mdb') do ren %%A_%%B %%A.mdb
```

This should help get you started. Please post a new question with specifics on what you have tried and what isn't working if you run into troubles crafting the batch file.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the first steps, I have realized that the link for files is on internet not on intranet. So I edited my question (Step1) So I think I should use another function in order to download files from internet (asking login and password if it's not saved on cache)

Comment: I've started by renaming function. Your rename code works fine with      "_" delimiter but when I try to use it with "-" delimiter it does not work, do I make sth. wrong? Just replaced "_" by "-" in the code -->     for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %%A in ('dir /b *.mdb') do ren %%A_%%B %%A.mdb

Comment: The updates to your question changed the file names to use multiple hyphens rather than a single underscore to separate the name and date. You'll need to change the rename code to: `for /f "tokens=1* delims=-" %%A in ('dir /b *.mdb') do ren "%%A-%%B" "%%A.mdb"`

Comment: I see you also changed "Intranet" to "Internet". That's a bit trickier to do from a batch file, but it is possible: [How to download files from the command line](http://superuser.com/questions/25538/how-to-download-files-from-command-line-in-windows-like-wget-is-doing).

Comment: Yes, that's why I've added a comment under the question.I don't know why the renaming code does not work with " - " sign? Which part of the code do I have to change to rename FILE-Date?

Comment: The original renaming code looks for an underscore in the file name and separates that file name into two tokens. FILE_DATE.mdb becomes FILE and DATE. If you replace the underscore with a hyphen and run it against FILE-26-01-2015, you will only get "FILE" and "26". We need it to be "FILE" and "26-01-2015". For this reason, we also need to update how the tokens are defined. That's why the new code uses "tokens=1*" in addition to "delims=-". `for /f "tokens=1* delims=-" %%A in ('dir /b *.mdb') do ren "%%A-%%B" "%%A.mdb"`

Comment: Thank you @Tyler for your fast solutions. I just have downloading issue to be solved, I'm trying to understand wget structure but did not succeed yet.